# How Can I Me And My Friends Connect our Notes App Together

Tags: android, ios, godot

I am trying to make app that you use to wright down your goals and can check off every day that you worked on it. I am going to set it up like a notes app but I want to have it as like a shared notes app so others can see that you are working on your goals and not slacking off. While I can set up almost everything for it I have no idea how to make the app update on other peoples phone, I don`t know if I will need to set up a server but I am hoping that I can get around that. I am new to programming and so I have not tried anything yet. Sorry if its vague, I can not think of any other way besides a server but that would not be worth it since this is just for me and a couple friends.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to share data in some form, it requires server. Your note's data needs to be stored centrally instead of locally, and then be accessed by your apps across devices.